# Common rows of two .txt files in python

Tags: python, text

I have 2 big .txt files and each file has 10 columns and 21008 rows. I need to get the common rows of two files and create a new file. The first column of two files include the IDs. Some of the IDs in 2 files are similar but not all of them. The new files would contain the common IDs and of course the complete row. Here is a small example:

**input1:**

```
ENSG00000137288.5   0,111111112 0,099415205 0,894736842 
ENSG00000116085.9   0,086826347 0,152694613 1,758620722 
ENSG00000167578.12  0,052093968 0,096016347 1,843137535 
ENSG00000167531.2   0,042553194 0,085106388 2   
ENSG00000078237.4   0,016129032 0   0   0,031746034
```

**input2:**

```
ENSG00000137288.5   0,167213112 0,134426236 0,803921621 
ENSG00000116032.5   0,094311371 0,144461095 1,531746311 
ENSG00000167578.12  0,062894806 0,101620428 1,615720507 
ENSG00000103227.14  0,067720085 0,068472534 1,011111165 
ENSG00000078241.8   0,016260162 0,040650405 2,5
```

**output file:**

```
ENSG00000137288.5   0,111111112 0,099415205 0,894736842 ENSG00000137288.5   0,167213112 0,134426236 0,803921621     
ENSG00000167578.12  0,052093968 0,096016347 1,843137535 ENSG00000167578.12  0,062894806 0,101620428 1,615720507
```

Thanks

Comment: May either of the files contain duplicate rows?

Comment: no. there is no duplicated row in each file.

Comment: I don't really mind if that is included or not.

Answer (score 0):

Read the first file and iterate line by line, for each line keep the id and line. Do it for the next one only this time find the common lines by id and append then to a list in the output format:

```
ids = {}
found = []
with open(filepath1) as file1:
    for line in file1.lines():
        id_ = line.split()[0]
        ids[id_] = line

with open(filepath2) as file2:
    for line in file2.lines():
        id_ = line.split()[0]
        if id_ in ids:
            found.append("{} {}".format(ids[id_], line))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` to keep track of seen lines from the second file to allow the first to set the order:

```
d2={}
with open("f2.txt") as f2:
    for line in f2:
        k,_,v=line.partition(' ')
        d2[k]=line.strip()

with open("f1.txt") as f1:
    for line in f1:
        k,_,v=line.partition(' ')
        if k in d2:
            print line.strip(), d2[k]
```

Prints:

```
ENSG00000137288.5   0,111111112 0,099415205 0,894736842 ENSG00000137288.5   0,167213112 0,134426236 0,803921621
ENSG00000167578.12  0,052093968 0,096016347 1,843137535 ENSG00000167578.12  0,062894806 0,101620428 1,615720507
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution (using lists) for your problem. At the end, you're going to get a list with all the rows with the same ID in a file named "res"

```
l1 = []
l2 = []

with open('file1', 'r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        line = line.split()
        l1.append(line)

with open('file2', 'r') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        line = line.split()
         l2.append(line)

res = [i + j for i, j in zip(l1, l2) if i[0] == j[0]]

target = open('res', 'w')
for i in res:
    for j in i:
        target.write(j)
        target.write(' ')
    target.write('\n')
```